# Why don't set the var (Dart)

Tags: dart, dart-async

I'm trying this in Dart:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:html';

class testHandler {

  Map parsedJSON;

  testHandler();

  void Initialize(){
    String rawJSON = "core/testConfiguration.json";

    HttpRequest.getString(rawJSON)
    .then((String f) => parsedJSON.from(JSON.decode(f)))
    .catchError((Error e) => print(e.toString()));

    print(parsedJSON);
  }
}
```

If you see I'm setting *`parsedJSON`* in `.then()` but when I'm trying to get the var, it returns null.

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions under the `dart-async` tag.

Answer (score 2):

`print(parsedJSON);` is executed before `getString()` returns. `getString()` is async and the callback passed to `then()` will be executed sometimes later after `getString()` returned the result but `print(parsedJSON);` will be executed immediately.

Using `async`/`await` makes this quite easy:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:html';

class testHandler {

  Map parsedJSON;

  testHandler();

  Future Initialize() async {
    String rawJSON = "core/testConfiguration.json";

    try {
      String f = await HttpRequest.getString(rawJSON);
      parsedJSON = JSON.decode(f);
    } catch(Error e) { 
      print(e.toString());
    } 

    print(parsedJSON);
  }
}
```

Async is contagious therefore code calling `Initialize()` has to wait for it to finish as well.

Comment: Thanks mate, how i tell you, i'm learning dart and i'm still learning async programming in dart, now i understamd my mistake.

Comment: If this answers your questions please mark it as answered with the checkmark below the upvote buttons. For more information about async programming in Dart see https://www.dartlang.org/articles/await-async/ https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/futures/ https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/streams/ https://www.dartlang.org/articles/beyond-async/

Comment: I have another question, how i can access to parsedJSON from another class and set other variable with parsedJSON from the other class?

Comment: `var th = new testHandler(); th.parsedJSON = {'x':'y'};` Is this what you are asking for?

Comment: No exactly, im trying to use the parsed json, to use them in another class, for example, i'll write a function to returns some data of the already parsed json, but in another class.

Comment: "Words are cheap. Show me some code." Linus Torvalds. Can you add code to your question that shows what you try to accomplish and explain what doesn't work as expected. I really don't understand what causes you troubles.

Comment: `Map<String, String> getTests(String data){
    if(!parsedJSON.containsKey(data)) return null;
    return parsedJSON[data];
  }` I Have this function in the same class of parsedJSON if i want to use in another "foo" class, it returns null.

Answer (score 0):

No, you are not setting `parsedJSON` in `.then()`. You are trying to call method from null object. Before use `parsedJSON` you should set it with `=` operator, like

```
parsedJSON = new Map.from(JSON.decode(f));
```

In other words, you mixed up parsedJSON's methods and Map's constructors.

**P.S.** 
And, as Gunter denoted it, you may write it shortly:

```
parsedJSON = JSON.decode(f);
```